# Does TTL in Document DB (Cosmos DB) affect to index?

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, ttl

I am using Document DB. 
In previous days, I changed index of database and receive some "Not found document" error due to index transformation. 
I also plan to enable TimeToLive features of document DB but Azure alert:

> Changing the TTL or Indexing Policy impacts query results while the
>   index transformation occurs

If TTL is enabled, will "Not found document" or other negative impact happen again ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Please see the following: [Indexing policies and TTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#indexing-policies-and-ttl)

> The Time-to-Live (TTL) feature requires indexing to be active on the container it is turned on. This means that:
>
> - it is not possible to activate TTL on a container where the indexing mode is set to None,
> - it is not possible to set the indexing mode to None on a container where TTL is activated.
>
> For scenarios where no property path needs to be indexed, but TTL is required, you can use an indexing policy with:
>
> - an indexing mode set to Consistent, and
> - no included path, and
> - /* as the only excluded path.